# is there a way to dynamically load js file as es6 module? (like $.getScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I want to load JavaScript dynamically, therefore I'm widely using jQuery Ajax calls in order to that.
The thing is, I want to load some of the dynamically called .js files as ES6 modules.
In order to do so, I need to add `type="module"` in the script tag call in the HTML body.
Since I'm using jQuery to call the .js file, how can I pass the `type="module"` behavior to the Ajax call?

This is the exception I'm getting when I'm using ES6 import syntax in a dynamically fetched file:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

This is my Ajax synced call to fetch the .js file:

```
jQuery.loadScriptSync = function (url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: false
    });
};
```

I want to know if there is a built-in jQuery method or library to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Just manually create a `<script>` element, set the `type` and `src` attributes, then append it to `document.body`.

Comment: I'm dynamically loading the HTML page as well, so the ".ready()" method won't work if I would just inject a <script> tag.

Comment: So inject the script when loading the HTML has finished?

Comment: as you can see in the function above, I'm loading the script synchronically, I need it to fully load before jumping to the next instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to load JS files dynamically it is possible to use `dynamic imports`:

```
import('yourFile').then(() => ...)
```

Some info on it on Webpack page https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ and there https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import

Comment: This is about using modules in the browser, as far as I can see. Not well supported yet, but possible.

Comment: your imported files may export ES6 modules with no problems- I've been using this feature a lot in few projects